# Arithmetic comparison of objects in C#

Tags: c#

I have two `object` instances which could be integers or doubles. I want to find out which is the smaller:

```
int ix = 1;
int iy = 2;
object ox = ix;
object oy = iy;
if (ox < oy) // This is an error
{
...
}
```

Is it possible to perform this comparison without hideously inefficient-looking

```
if (ox.GetType() == typeof(int))
{
}
else if (ox.GetType() == typeof(double))
{
}
```

tests?

Comment: Where do the objects come from? (why aren't they int/double?)

Comment: @Richard: you can't unbox directly an `int` to a `double`

Comment: @Sayse the objects come from a third-party arithmetic expression evaluation library so I can't know a priori what the types are (they are not restricted to ints and doubles in the library, it handles strings and arrays too).

Comment: @JulianGold - Fair enough, was just wondering if there was an underlying issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interface, [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for that

> Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a value type or class implements to order or sort its instances.

and

> All numeric types (such as Int32 and Double) implement IComparable, as do String, Char, and DateTime. Custom types should also provide their own implementation of IComparable to enable object instances to be ordered or sorted.

You could write...

```
int ix = 1;
int iy = 2;
object ox = ix;
object oy = iy;

IComparable cx = ox as IComparable;

// Does our type supports comparison?
if (cx == null && ox != null)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

if ((cx != null && cx.CompareTo(oy) < 0) || (ox == null && oy != null)) // x < y
{

}
```

Note the special case handling for `ox == null`

Mmmh... shorter..

```
int cmp = System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare(ox, oy);

if (cmp < 0) {
}
```

It seems that the `System.Collections.Comparer` does everything necessary (using the `IComparable` interface)

You can even use

```
int cmp = System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(ox, oy);
```

The `object` type doesn't support the `IComparable<object>`, so the `IComparer` interface will be used (in truth, in the .NET 4.5 implementation, the `Comparer<object>.Default` will use the `Comparer.Default` of the previous example :-) )

**IMPORTANT: in all these cases, `ox` and `oy` MUST be of the same type (or `null`). You CAN'T mix `int` and `double`.**

Answer (score 1):

If you "know" that the types can be compared, but:

1. You don't know the exact type (without reflection)
2. You don't know if they're even the same type

Then the way to do this is by using `dynamic`:

```
void Main()
{
    int ix = 1;
    int iy = 2;
    dynamic ox = ix;
    dynamic oy = iy;

    if (ox < oy)
        Debug.WriteLine("ox < oy");
    else if (ox == oy)
        Debug.WriteLine("ox == oy");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("ox > oy");
}
```

Please note that `dynamic` is like an `object` in many cases, but will defer until runtime the exact binding and handling. This means that the above code would throw an exception at runtime if `ox` and/or `oy` happen to be types that doesn't know how to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDouble(ox).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(oy));
```

This will of course throw an `InvalidCastException` if one of them is not a number.